# too many redirects on wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, configuration

I downloaded latest Wordpress (4.7.4) and installed it to my localhost (opensuse leap 42.2 with nginx & php-fpm), named it http://wp.local and noticed strange things.

When I open:
     http://wp.local - everything is great.
     http://wp.local/hello-world/ and other internal site links - everything is great.
    but when I open:
    http://wp.local/wp-admin - I got too many redirects error and blank 
    screen.
    For example http://wp.local/wp-admin/post-new.php - all is OK.
    http://wp.local/wp-admin/upload.php - all is OK
    http://wp.local/wp-admin/plugins.php - all is OK
    but http://wp.local/wp-admin/update-core.php - I got too many redirects 
    and blank screen.
    But when I try http://wp.local/**index.php**/wp-admin/update-core.php  -
    it redirects me to http://wp.local/wp-admin/update-core.php - and page 
    shows, all is ok.

I cant' figure out what is wrong, here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name wp.local;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/vitalik/www/wp.local;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.php?$args;
    }   
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri permanent;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;  
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }   
}
```

Comment: This: `rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri permanent;` looks like a loop to me.

Comment: removed and tried, but no luck :(

Comment: Did you reload / restart nginx after that change?

Comment: Yes I did restart, but problem is still present